# How to set the mime type of a file with fwrite in PHP?

Tags: php, mime-types, fwrite, php-gtk

I need to create a .xls file and assign the correct mimetype to it. A simple `header()` statement didn't work probably because i'm using PHPGtk.

MSOffice gives me an error when opening the file, it says the content may not reflect the extension of the file, so i immediately thought it could be because of the mime type.

Currently, the code is (in a very malformed html snippet):

```
$table = '<table><thead><tr><th>Oi</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>opaopaopa</td></tr><tr><td>sjiasiaj</td></tr></tbody></table>';
      $handle = fopen('C:\opa.xls','w+');
      fwrite($handle, $table);
      fclose($handle);
```

Comment: This code needs no MIME type, because the file is written to disk. Do you plan to ouput the file to a user via the browser?

Comment: @George No, the file will be written to disk, no browser involved.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, the files don't have mime types.  They are identified by their extension only.

Comment: I asked the question because MSOffice gives me an error when opening the file, it says the content may not reflect the extension of the file, so i immediately thought it could be because of the mime type.

Comment: @jorge: That's because you're writing an html file (without proper `<html>` and `<body>` tags, but are naming it .xls.

Comment: @Jorge: It would be advantageous to everyone if you put that information in your question. I'm not criticizing. It's just a thought.

Comment: @Marc Yes, but can i set the mime to anything else so Office won't bitch about it?

Comment: Not on the file itself. You could try putting a `<meta>` tag into a `<head>` block, but I don't know if Windows or Office will looking that far into the file before deciding to spit out that error

Comment: @Jorge, put .html on the end of it.  You can't create an HTML file with an XLS extension and expect Excel to think by default that it is a genuine Excel spreadsheet file.

Comment: @Brad But i don't need an HTML file. If i needed i'd just change the extension. :P

Comment: @Jorge.... then why are you outputting an HTML file.  You have a large disconnect here.  Your code itself is outputting HTML, and you are naming it XLS.  If you want XLS, output XLS.  If you output HTML, name it .HTML.

Comment: @Brad Because i don't have available time to implement a class that generates and outputs and .xls, only because of that. (As in "the deadline is in 10 hours and i'm way behind getting things done, we're a team of 3 pulling an all nighter at this very moment.)